# Changing the font size of Tab information in Iterm

Tags: macos, fonts, iterm2

I use a High Resolution external monitor at work and increase the font size in my terminal for better visibility.

But the text on the tab bar is stuck at the default size. Changing the font size does not affect the font size of the tab and I could not find any setting I could tweak to achieve the same.

[image: Tab font size is way small than text in the terminal]

Trying to zoom in using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> also only affects text inside the terminal and not the tabs.

How do I change the font size of text in the tab?

Comment: Which text in your image are you referring to? Please [edit] the question and be explicit.

Comment: You need to adjust the screen resolution in Display CP, you cannot independently resize OS elements.

Comment: @Tetsujin but is it as OS level element? iTerm has options to control the dimensions and colours of these tabs, so I am guessing it could in theory also control the font sizes.

Comment: Hmmm... looking at it again, it may not be an OS element, but idk how you may be able to tweak it from iTerm itself, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to prefs > advanced and search for "tab font". You need to enable custom font sizes and then you can set the point size there. This change takes effect as soon as you exit preferences; no need to restart terminal (at least on V3.4).

[image]